# Kotlin Ktor trying to install JsonFeature on the client side but is not recognized

Tags: json, kotlin, serialization, plugins, ktor

I'm using Ktor client and I'm trying to implement post requests using the serialization provided by the framework.

For some odd reason adding serialization works on the server side but not the client side.

Gradle

```kotlin
plugins {
    application
    kotlin("jvm") version "1.6.10"
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.plugin.serialization") version "1.6.10"
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url = uri("https://maven.pkg.jetbrains.space/public/p/ktor/eap") }
}

dependencies {
    // Ktor server
    implementation("io.ktor:ktor-server-core-jvm:$ktor_version")
    implementation("io.ktor:ktor-server-content-negotiation-jvm:$ktor_version")
    implementation("io.ktor:ktor-serialization-kotlinx-json-jvm:$ktor_version")
    implementation("io.ktor:ktor-server-netty-jvm:$ktor_version")

    // Ktor client
    implementation("io.ktor:ktor-client-core:$ktor_version")
    implementation("io.ktor:ktor-client-cio:$ktor_version")
    implementation("io.ktor:ktor-client-json:$ktor_version")
    implementation("io.ktor:ktor-client-serialization:$ktor_version")

    // Arrow
    implementation("io.arrow-kt:arrow-core:1.0.1")

    // Tests
    implementation("ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:$logback_version")
    testImplementation("io.ktor:ktor-server-tests-jvm:$ktor_version")
    testImplementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-test-junit:$kotlin_version")
}
```

In my client side

```kotlin
import io.ktor.client.*
import io.ktor.client.engine.cio.*
import io.ktor.client.plugins.*
import io.ktor.client.request.*
import io.ktor.client.statement.*
import io.ktor.http.*
import io.ktor.util.*
import kotlinx.coroutines.launch
import kotlinx.coroutines.runBlocking
import kotlinx.serialization.*

@Serializable
data class TastyCredentials(val login: String, val password: String)

@OptIn(InternalAPI::class)
class TastyWorksBroker() : Broker {

    companion object {
        val client = HttpClient(CIO) {
            install(JsonFeature) // JsonFeature is not recognized by IntelliJ

            defaultRequest {
                url(baseUrl)
                contentType(ContentType.Application.Json)

            }
        }
    }

    override suspend fun connect(): Boolean {
        val response: HttpResponse = client.post("/sessions") {
            body = TastyCredentials(login, password)
        }

        //
    }
```

install(JsonFeature) does not work, I also tried this:

```kotlin
install(ContentNegotiation) {
                json()
            }
```

Does not work either...

Any help?

Answer (score 14):

I actually needed to add another dependency for the client side content negotiation

`implementation("io.ktor:ktor-client-content-negotiation:$ktor_version")`

Solved